# 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in Windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I try to access jupyter via cmd it gives me the error line in the title.
I'm using python 3.8.5 and installed jupyter via pip using `pip install jupyter` command and it showed me the following message in the cmd line

```
>pip install jupyter
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-console in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (6.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (6.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (4.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (7.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\this pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site- 
packages (from jupyter) (5.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (5.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\this pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site- 
packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter) (3.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter) (6.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in c:\users\this pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site- 
packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter) (7.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (5.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\this pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site- 
packages (from notebook->jupyter) (19.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=5.0 in c:\users\this pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site- 
packages (from notebook->jupyter) (6.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.6.1 in c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (4.6.3)
...
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\this 
pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

After that I tried to access jupyter notebook by the following cmd line `python -m jupyter` command but instead of opening in a web browser it is showing me the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\this pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in 
_run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\users\this pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\jupyter- 
notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
File "c:\users\this pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site- 
packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in <module>
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in 
 <module>
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 
40, in <module>
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, 
in reraise
raise value
 File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 
 27, in <module>
_ns = select_backend(first)
 File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 
 28, in select_backend
 mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
 File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
 packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' 
(most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

**Note that**

1. I've already added python to the environment variable so there's nothing wrong there. I checked twice.

In the path folder I've these items

[image: path folder items]

so what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **jupyter notebook** alone. From my knowledge, python -m is for referencing modules and it could just be causing problems.

Comment: Tried that too...but same problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, I had to reinstall everything and add another path option to the environment variable which is `C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts` the previous path was in the local folder and this one is in the Roaming folder.
This did the trick for me.